# Пиксели, em, проценты, а пустое значение?

Tags: css, css3

В некоторых свойствах мы не указываем `px`, `em` или проценты, а просто указываем, к примеру, `свойство: 0`. А что мы присваиваем? Почему нет `px` и т. д.?

Comment: Ноль это такое специальное исключение которому не обязательно указывать единицу изменения. Потому что 0 пикселей и 0 em-ов это одно и то же. Впрочем, при этом есть случаи когда даже у ноля нужно указывать.

Comment: Потому что `0px` == `0rem` == `0%` == `0mm` == ... == `0{чегоУгодно}`. И ноль все же обозначает не отсутствие значения (пустоту), а скорее "точку отсчета у непрерывных числовых величин".

Comment: Указывать после нуля единицы измерения можно (такое значение в CSS будет валидным), а плохой практикой это считается просто потому, что указание юнитов у нуля не имеет практического смысла (оно ни на что не влияет технически, и только затрудняет восприятие).

Comment: Ноль можно не указывать, если есть нормализация css (кстати рекомендую **normalize.css** [https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css]) и/или вы уверены в наследуемости. Но всё же. В ключевых значениях, например margin или padding, ноль рекомендую проставлять. Во избежание всяческих ошибок.